# Trigger que actualice un campo cada 24h

Tags: mysql, sql

Como crear un trigger para que actualice el valor 'fecha' y el valor 'horario' de todos los alumnos de la tabla 1 a '-' (guión), cada 24h. Antes de hacerlo debe de insertar el valor que hubiera en la tabla 1 en la tabla 2.

He probado lo siguiente sin resultado:

```
DELIMITER // create trigger actualizar_datos BEFORE update on 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ), "%H:%i:%S" ) = '00:00:00' UPDATE tabla1 set horario='-', fecha='-' for each row INSERT INTO tabla2(id,fecha, horario) VALUES (id, 
fecha_antigua, horario_antiguo); end // DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El tema que buscas lo podemos analizar así:

**Los triggers**

Son disparadores que van a ocurrir en cuanto alguna de las sigueintes accciones se lleve a cabo:

- INSERT
- UPDATE
- DELETE
- ......

Teniendo 2 momentos donde esto puede ocurrir, los cuales son:

- BEFORE
- AFTER

Lo cual nos explica que:

Un *trigger* antes o después de alguna de las 4 acciones indicadas arriba.

**Referencia**

- [triggers en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)

**Los events**

Por otro lado y dado el contexto de tu pregunta, el motor de bases de datos nos propone una solución un tanto mas acorde.

Los eventos programados son acciones que se van a ejecutar en el periodo de tiempo que le sea programado, para inmediatamente después ejecutar alguna acción o acciones sobre los datos.

**Referencias**

- [eventos en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html)

**Sintaxis**

Para el caso de los eventos, tenemos esto:

```
CREATE EVENT nombreEvento
    ON SCHEDULE 24 HOUR
DO
    //Acción de UPDATE sobre los datos establecidos;
```

Hasta este punto tendríamos cubierto parte del requerimiento de la pregunta, sin embargo queda pendiente:

> Antes de hacerlo debe de insertar el valor que hubiera en la tabla 1 en la tabla 2.

Lo cual ahora si podemos *atacar* a través de un *trigger*, lo cual podemos tratarlo así:

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER insertaDespues BEFORE UPDATE ON tabla1
 FOREACH ROW
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tabla2(col1, col2) VALUES (old.value1, old.value2);
END ;
//
```

**Observaciones**

- Tu trigger debe ser *before update* para que de esta forma este en línea con el evento que actuará para hacer una actualización de los datos de la tabla1
- El trigger verificará que antes de hacer una actualización de los datos de tabla1, mande estos mismos a la tabla2, entonces debemos usar la sintaxis de `OLD.valor` para indicar que tome un valor ya existente
- Tu trigger no debe verificar un *BEFORE INSERT* por que toda la idea gira en que esa inserción se lleve a cabo siempre y cuando exista el evento de actualización.

Comment: Perfecto, menuda aclaración. Gracias.